# Rails - iterate over db entries in one field, separated by linebreaks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iteration, line-breaks, separator

In my application I have a products model which has among other things four fields for image paths. I use this to build a slide show.

However,  I would love to have all those paths in one big text field and seperate them by whatever works (linebreak would be the easiest to handle in the form).

I was thinking something like:

```
<% for ... in @screenshots %>  
    <%= lightbox_to(@product.screenshot, @product.screenshot, "screenshots") %>  
<% end %>
```

and would be hoping for that to result in:

```
<%= lightbox_to(@product.screenshot1, @product.screenshot1, "screenshots") %>  
<%= lightbox_to(@product.screenshot2, @product.screenshot2, "screenshots") %>  
<%= lightbox_to(@product.screenshot3, @product.screenshot3, "screenshots") %>  
...
```

Your input is greatly appreciated!

Val

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have all links in one text field, then you can use [split](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000803).

```
<% @product.screenshots.split.each do |screenshot| %>
  <%= lightbox_to(screenshot, screenshot, "screenshots" %>
<% end %>
```

By default it will split on whitespaces. But you can define splitting condition by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming @product has_many screenshots (and if not, use @screenshots instead of @product.screenshots below).

```
<% @product.screenshots.each do |screenshot| %>
   <%= lightbox_to(screenshot, screenshot, "screenshots") %>
<% end %>
```

(this assumes lightbox_to is being invoked correctly)

If product really has separate members named 'screenshot1', 'screenshot2', etc., then do this:

```
<% [:screenshot1, :screenshot2, :screenshot3].each do |screenshot_name|
   screenshot = @product.send screenshot_name %>
  <%= lightbox_to(screenshot, screenshot, "screenshots") %>
<% end %>`
```

Comment: you can't use this solution where the paths of the screenshots are together in one field of the Product-model